# JMeter WebDriver Sampler doesn't work with latest Firefox version

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

I use JMeter WebDriver Sampler (JMeter v4.0) for Chrome Driver (where I specify the path to chromedriver in `jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config`), and it works.

Now I want to try with latest Firefox Browser (FF Quantum v59.0), but it doesn't work. FF browser is opened but it doesn't go further, ex `WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')` is not executed.

It seems JMeter WebDriver Sampler doesn't catch up with geckodriver and changes of FF. I google it, but I don't find any info on this regard. Does anyone know any update on this? Is there any workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at JMeter [Firefox Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/) plugin restrictions:

> the latest Firefox version may not work with the latest WebDriver set. The table below describes the version of Firefox that is compatible with JMeterPlugins:

Current version is compatible only with version 26 of Firefox

Also [firefox jmeter addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jmeter/) is not compatible

> This add-on is not compatible with your version of Firefox.
>
> Not compatible with Firefox Quantum

Comment: Thanks, so I have to stick around with Chrome for now

Answer (score 1):

The jmeter firefox driver config is only compatible with firefox 26, 33 and the latest is 45 and 46.

You cannot use the version of firefox which is greater than 46.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the geckodriver file path in environment variable "Path". If not try that. I am using latest firefox with Jmeter Webdriver and is working for me.

Computer Properties - Advance System Settings - Environment Variables - Path (Add File Path without File name)